# Finding a likelihood ratio function

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, likelihood-ratio

Let $X_{11},X_{12},\ldots,X_{1n_1}$ be a random sample from $normal(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$, where $\mu_1\in\mathbb{R}$ is unknown and $\sigma^2>0$ is known. Further let, $X_{21},X_{22},\ldots,X_{2n_1}$ be a random sample from $normal(\mu_2,\sigma^2)$, where $\mu_2\in\mathbb{R}$ is unknown.

I want to conduct an LRT for testing the hypothesis $H_0:\mu_1\ge\mu_2$ vs. $H_1:\mu_1<\mu_2$.

I am not able to find out the likelihood ratio function.
Can someone please help me?